# Converting aspx file from VB to C# error 500.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis

I have used https://github.com/icsharpcode/CodeConverter tool to convert a project from VB to C#. The conversion wasn't perfect, but I have managed to resolve issues mentioned in: https://github.com/icsharpcode/CodeConverter/issues/175, namely:

- update Language="VB" to Language="C#"
- .aspx fileshave CodeBehind tag changed from ".vb" -> "*.cs"

I am hosting my application locally on IIS and ever since conversion I get an error:

[image]

I have tried refreshing the IIS pools, the pool type is set to `integrated`, I have tried to  use Visual Studio and Rider to run the app. It compiles, goes through authorization and authentication but then I end up on this page, with little to no clue what might have gone wrong.

Comment: After convert, did u run in VS and check is it working or not ? Actually this url working https://i.stack.imgur.com/ and u open png which contain error page like above

Comment: I have, it builds, but it fails in runtime

Comment: What error ? pls share screenshot

Comment: The screenshot is in the descritpion...

Comment: try this solution https://prnt.sc/UtUMtq_MNLH5

Comment: Probably will need to attach debugger to the iis process and step through the code to find actual error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2022

Comment: Eventually I have found some more errors in the event viewer log for Windows. Obviously I have tried to debug it locally, but it wouldn't throw any exception.

Comment: You can try this methods: expand website and click on Application Pools. In the right window, right-click on AppPool and selects Advanced Settings. Select “Enable 32-bit Applications” and change it from False to True. Click OK and restart your computer.